# Use class pointer as template argument?

Tags: c++, class

Is it possible to use a class pointer as template argument of same templated class? for example:

```
template<my_class* p>
class my_class 
{
     ...
}
```

Comment: Did you try it and see?

Comment: @GBlodgett  how do you declare a variable of this class if you need a class pointer?

Comment: What exactly are you hoping to use this for? How is what you are asking different from just using a pointer to the class?

Comment: The Curiously Recurring Template Pattern.

Comment: Your question to GBlodgett is your answer. And that's it if you only asked due to academic curiosity. Otherwise this is an [XY question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), and you should ask about the X that led to this Y.

Comment: @StoryTeller well I guess that it is not possible, i wanted to know if there it was a "smart" way to declare this or using forward declaration etc